# VBA Acess Function - Return Outlook Folder/Inbox as object

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

```
Private OutlookApp, Nms As Object


Sub TestSub()
Dim Fold As Object

Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set Nms = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")


Set Fold = outlookFolderpath("Test Folder")

For Each Email In Fold.Items ' This loop doesnt work
Debug.Print Email.Subject
Next


End Sub

Private Function outlookFolderpath(Inbox As String) As Object
Dim fold_name As String

Set OutlookFolder_Path = Nms.Folders(Inbox).Folders("Inbox")

For Each Email In OutlookFolder_Path.Items ' This Loop works
Debug.Print Email.Subject
Next


End Function
```

Hello,
I was hoping someone could help me with the above code. I'm trying to Set and inbox folder path from a function and using it within the sub.
It works fine from within the function but not when setting it in the sub?
Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I get a runtime error '91' - Object variable or With block variable not set
so I would gather that the function is not returning the object but I'm not sure why?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the object from the function, so

`Set OutlookFolder_Path = Nms.Folders(Inbox).Folders("Inbox")`

should be

`Set outlookFolderpath = Nms.Folders(Inbox).Folders("Inbox")`

If you declare `Option Explicit` at the top of your code you will be less likely to run into problems like this as all your variable should be declared.

Comment: Hello, sorry the _ was a typo, I made a cut down version of my script for the purpose of the example. You did lead me to the answer though as I needed to DIm Email as object for this to work so thanks of the "Option Explicit" tip